# is it possible to get response of previewed Pdf in Retrofit android?

Tags: android, pdf, retrofit2

**I am getting 500 from response but in postman its showing 200**

[response that I am getting in body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cabBN.png)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQYkA.png)

**My ApiInterface**

```
@Streaming
@GET("SaleReport")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/pdf"})
Call<ResponseBody> getReport(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("SaleId") String saleId);
```

**Retrofit Call**

```
private void getSalesReport(String saleId) {
    if (saleId != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + saleId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ApiClient.getInstance(this).getApi().getReport("Bearer " + Constant.Token, saleId)
                .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("PDF","Success");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("PDF",""+response.code());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("PDF", "" + t.toString());
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "SaleId Required", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***It's a back-end side issue....
They need session to access the pdf.
Although I have solved it by sending a session from previous request and sent it as a header.***